# Add/Remove Event Listener to/from child Movie Clip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

In short, here is what I'd like to accomplish:

1. Click Movie Clip, add child
2. Click child movie clip, play sound
3. Click child again, stop sound
4. Click child a third time, remove child

Sadly, I've only gotten as far as step 1. I've figured out how to get a sound to play when the parent movie clip is clicked (I'm using linkage), but when I attempt the same after with the child, I get the following error:

<strike>TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.</strike> (I'm no longer getting this error)

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 29  1120: Access of undefined property newBox.

```
    leftBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBox);
    function addBox(event:MouseEvent):void 

    {
    var newBox:right_box = new right_box();
    addChild(newBox);
    newBox.x = 0;
    newBox.y = 0;
    newBox.width = leftBox.width;
    newBox.height = leftBox.height /2;

    }
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
    function playSound(event:Event)
    {
    var mySound:testSound = new testSound();
    mySound.play();

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

(P.S. I'm a n00b, so please, be nice!)

Comment: Please add your code snippet which you think is problematic to the question.

Comment: @Ihsan, I just added the snippet. But the problem is definitely the playSound function. Everything works fine when I comment it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an event listener to newbox, before it is created.. Try it as follows:

```
// mySound should be availible in scope
var mySound:testSound = new testSound();

// newBox also
var newBox:right_box;
// here is a channel for you
var channel: SoundChannel;

// ok this adds the first listener...
leftBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBox);


function addBox(event:MouseEvent):void {
    newBox = new right_box();
    addChild(newBox);
    newBox.x = 0;
    newBox.y = 0;
    newBox.width = leftBox.width;
    newBox.height = leftBox.height /2;
    // you should add listener here...
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
    // you have to avoid multiple newBoxes on each other and
    // leaving the older ones under..
    // So stop listening to the newBox generating event: 
    leftBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBox);
}

function playSound(event:Event){
    channel = mySound.play();
    // On next click you want sound to stop so
    // First remove the old listener to avoid play over:  
    newBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
    // and hook listener to stop method
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
 }

 function stopSound(event:Event){
    channel.stop();
    // On next click you want to remove newBox 
    // First remove the old listener to avoid play over:  
    newBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
    newBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeNewBox);
 }

 function removeNewBox(event:Event){
    // First remove the listener :  
    newBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeNewBox );
    removeChild(newBox); // now remove from display list
    newBox = null; // make contents eligible for garbage collection 
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting an "1120: Access of undefined property newBox" on 'newBox.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);'.

Comment: Because you've defined it as a var in a function so, it is not availible out of the function scope (symbol newBox points to nothing)...

Comment: I was thinking that might be part of my problem! But since I'm using it with a MouseEvent, what syntax would make sense?

Comment: Generally you have to learn scope concept... Scope in this context means the visibility or accessibility of variables and methods from different code hierarchies. And I think it will work now. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, it never occurred to me to simply declare the variables! I figured I needed the newBox outside of the function, but I guess I needed a more experienced set of eyes... It works, except for the `stop();`. I think I have to create a new sound channel. Will try that and report back.

Comment: A gift for you, now this has a channel... :)